# Laravel hasOne vs belongsTo returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm trying to return values of two tables that have relationship, but I'm receiving `null`.

Here in my **Controller** I'm passing `with('image')`.

```
$products = Produtos::select('codigo', 'descricao', 'CT', 'Fotos')->with('image')->take(2)->get();
return response()->json($products);
```

**Image Model**

```
class Objetos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Imagens';

    public function produtos(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Produtos::class);
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
class Produtos extends Model
{
    public function image(){
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Objetos::class, 'Chave');
    }
}
```

The columns that have relationship are:

`Objetos.Chave = Produtos.id`

I can't see my error, but I think it's probably in the arguments I'm passing in `hasOne` and `belongsTo`.

*Note: I'm accessing an external database (MS SQL), but I think it is not the problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change the relationship on the `Image` model, your `foreign key` does not follow laravel [naming conventions](https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/) and you have to specify it, like you did on the `Product` model, i.e.:

```php
public function produtos(){
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Produtos::class, 'Chave');
}
```

But the real problem is in your query:

```php
Produtos::select('codigo', 'descricao', 'CT', 'Fotos')->with('image')->take(2)->get();
```

Here you missed to add `id` to the **selected** fields then laravel is unable to `eager load` the related `Image` models, so you should change the line like this:

```php
Produtos::select('id', 'codigo', 'descricao', 'CT', 'Fotos')->with('image')->take(2)->get();
```

IMHO my advice is to not restrict the fields retrieved on a model with a `select()`, you can incur with this kind of errors if you have relationships in place.

Comment: Now I've got an error `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. Is that because I'm trying to return an image object as JSON? Is there a way to send image or save it in Laravel storage? An then, how can I get the image from external database, save in my own Laravel storage and substitute `with('image')` by storage link?

Comment: You cannot directly put an image or other binary data in a JSON, you can encode it, i.e. with `base64_encode()`, or send the link. But this should be another question.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: I'll do when I see that worked. As you said in your answer, `IMHO my advice is to not restrict the fields retrieved on a model with a select()`, if I do not specify fields, how can I specify field to send in return after I get data from database?

Comment: I explicit added `if you have relationship in place`, I didn't know your usage case, your question was about a relationship returning null and my advice was on that, I didn't know you need to retrict fields for JSON serialization, that IMHO deserve another question with the relevant code.